# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export - How to set up library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, es6-modules

I'm building a crypto library for my app (the app runs on react using electron).
The problem I have is that when I import the library in the react electron app I get the error "Unexpected token export".
I tried different babel configurations on the library to solve the problem but couldn't get any working.

Link to the library [crypto-notebook-lib](https://github.com/CryptoNotebook/crypto-notebook-lib)

Link to the app [crypto-notebook](https://github.com/CryptoNotebook/crypto-notebook)

Comment: It could mean plugin order is incorrect, so babel should be first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to use a build tool like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/) to compile your code into a library that can be consumed in your app.

A basic Webpack config to achieve that would look something like:

```
  var path = require('path');

  module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: 'crypto-notebook-lib.js',
      library: 'CryptoNotebookLib',
      libraryTarget: 'umd'
    }
  };
```

And then you would need to add it as a dependency in your crypto app through npm. The easiest way is to pull it [straight from GitHub](https://medium.com/@jonchurch/use-github-branch-as-dependency-in-package-json-5eb609c81f1a):

`$ npm install --save CryptoNotebook/crypto-notebook-lib#master`

Once it is installed as a dependency in your app, you can then `import` it as a package:

```
import CryptoNotebookLib from 'crypto-notebook-lib';
```

Comment: It's error with webpack. Similar error you can eccounter using browserify if you have wrong transforms order.

Comment: Thanks! I tried something like that as well, unfortunately, I couldn't make it work. I've added the webpack config to the project as I currently have it with your suggestion, but I'm still getting the error. Very frustrating I'm with this since 2 days :(

Comment: @JuanCruzMartinez You have to include your `/dist` folder with your code on git for it to work

Comment: I've noticed it works if I manually link the repo, and build it with webpack-cli, but if I install the module from npm, the build script is not running when installing and thus the module is not found.

Comment: Just saw your previous response. I understand... I can do that, however other libraries don't do it, I wonder if they perform a different solution?

Comment: Well you don't have to push the whole build folder, but you have to include the transpiled file that Webpack generates. Libraries like react just expose this file as `index.js` (`node_modules/react/index.js`). So you can name it whatever you want, you just need to make sure your `main` field in package.json points to that file.

Comment: I added all that and followed that guide and it's working now with the dist folder in the repo, I think it's good enough.
Thanks so much!